# How to replicate UObject inside UStruct?

Tags: c++, networking, unreal-engine4, multiplayer, replicate

```
    USTRUCT()
    struct FTestStruct
    {
        GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()
    
    private:
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        float Something;
    
        UPROPERTY()
        UMyObject* Object;
    };
```

I have this struct.

I wanna replicate it inside the actor and the float variable "Something" is replicated well,
But the UMyObject variable "Object" is not replicated at all.

How can I replicate it?

I already override GetLifetimeReplicatedProps though

```
void AMyActor::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray<FLifetimeProperty>& OutLifetimeProps) const
{
    Super::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(OutLifetimeProps);

    DOREPLIFETIME(AMyActor, TestStruct);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the replicated specifier on TestStructs uproperty(s) in AMyActor?

Comment: You are replicating a pointer to an object, an object that exists only on the server. On the client, this pointer will not be valid even if this object is replicated. Use a replicated function to create/find this object, or try to do everything on the client only. Additionally, if you are using a new version of the engine (4.27, 5.0) change GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY() to GENERATED_BODY()